# Apache Spark, with Python Pyspark AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' on Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have compiled the following code using Python on Databricks on Apache Spark but I keep on getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The complete error looks like the following:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4300703619637136> in <module>
     15 
     16       for field in field_list:
---> 17         entry = invoice.fields.get(field)
     18 
     19         if entry:
```

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

field_list = ["ContactNames","FirstName"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_list)


for blob in container.list_blobs():
  blob_url = container_url + "/" + blob.name
  poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_business_cards_from_url(business_card_url=blob_url)
  invoices = poller.result()
  print("Scanning " + blob.name + "...")
  
  for idx, invoice in enumerate(invoices):
      single_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_list)

      for field in field_list:
        entry = invoice.fields.get(field)
        
        if entry:
          single_df[field] = [entry.value]
          
      single_df['FileName'] = blob.name
      df = df.append(single_df)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

I feel the problem is quite simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked that your invoices are not empty or the fields not being present it, cause NoneType means there is no data in invoice.fields

Comment: Anjaneya, thanks for reaching out. It looks like you could be correct. Is there a way to modify the code to continue even if the field is empty?

Comment: put if else check for line that you suspect could be empty like 

 if invoice.fields is not None: entry = invoice.fields.get(field)